# how to make symbolic link between file in folders using perl?

Tags: perl

here is the scenario.

```
I have dir1-->file1
          |-->file2
          |-->subdir1--->file3
          |         |---> file4 
          | 
          |-->file1
          |-->subdir2-->file6
```

also dir2  different file tree...

I need to symlink above file in /path/dir1 and /path/dir2 to anthor path call /newpath/dir1 and /newpath/dir2..

is it possible?

So far i tried below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find qw(find);
my $path = "path";


find(\&Search, $path);

sub Search{
    my $filename = $File::Find::name;

    if(-f $filename){
     symlink("$filename", "path2");
     }
     }
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  So you have a directory `dir1` and you want to make a link to it, `/path/dir1` (so that `/path/dir1` is a link to `dir1`) -- is that what you want? Or do you mean to make links for individual files?

Comment: makes links for individual files.. Note : if there is a another dir in dir1 that should also be linked

Comment: OK, thank you.  Then it's indeed just a small fix to what you have

Comment: Note though, in your code with `if (-f $filename)` it won't do it for a subdirectory.  Perhaps you want to allow either, `if (-f $filename or -d $filename)` ?

Comment: ok ill change that and will see :D

Comment: That (add `-d`), and make it `symlink $filename, "path2/$_";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
symlink($filename, "path2/" . $_);
```

Should do the trick. Always assuming `"path2"` is the directory where you want the links to be place.

Comment: You should check for errors: `or die "symlink $filename to path2/ failed: $!";` It will throw an exception if symlinks are unimplemented, but not on standard filesystem errors.

Comment: can this use for symlink to dirs? Eg- like ln -s /abc/efc/ lmn/xfz ?
because i tried to do using symlink( ' /abc/efc/'  , 'lmn/xfz' . $_); 
got error `Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i went with below method.

```
    my $dir = "/path/";
    my $smlinkdir = "/smlink/path/";
    chdir($smlinkdir) or die "Cant chdir to $smlinkdir $!";
    if(-d $smlinkdir) {
    system(cp, '--recursive', '--preserve=all', '--no-dereference', '--symbolic-link', "$dir", "$smlinkdir");
    } else {
    exit 1
    }
```

this worked as well and i went with this since this gives the output i expected.